# Uncaught type error: $(...).datepicker() is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the jQuery datepicker function but I am receiving an error `Uncaught type error: $(...).datepicker() is not a function`. I have gone through my files and do not see a double reference to jQuery or incorrect file order in the `application.js`. Could someone help point out what might be the problem?

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <title>MyApp</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSS/Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!--  -->
</head>
<body>

  <%= render partial: "shared/top_info" %>

<%= yield %>




<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<!--  -->
</body>
</html>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ahoy
//= require_tree .

$('#customer_drop_off_date').datepicker();
```

**html.erb**

```
<% form_tag('/post') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:customer_drop_off_date) %>
<% end %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'
gem 'ahoy_matey'
gem 'geocoder'

group :development, :test do
  gem "pry"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "pry-stack_explorer"
  gem "pry-byebug"
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Where you require `datepicker` plugin?

Comment: I see you have done, `//= require_tree .` which will include all the script files. But do you have jquery_ui js inside your javascripts folder? Or any other datepicker plugin you're using?

Comment: I haven't yet, I am following the tutorial from Ryan Bates: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars?autoplay=true

Comment: @Kumar It was that I was missing this gem: https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` into your gemfile.

To require all jQuery UI modules, add the following to your application.js:

`//= require jquery-ui`

Into your stylesheets:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

[Gem docs](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using https://github.com/TrevorS/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.37'
```

Run:

```
bundle
```

---

Bootstrap CSS options (choose one):

- CDN in `.erb` as shown in question
- Rails Asset Pipeline https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails
- Install into `vendor/assets/` as described here: http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application

In application.css after bootstrap require:

```
*= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

---

In application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ahoy
//
// NEW (add these two lines)
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//
//= require_tree .

// OLD
//$('#customer_drop_off_date').datepicker();

// NEW
$('#customer_drop_off_date').datetimepicker();
```