# $(...).datepicker is not a function in Rails 6

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Can't understand why I cannot make any jQuery plugin functions (bootstrap, datepicker, etc.) work:

`$(...).datepicker()` or `$(...).modal()` respond with `... is not a function in Rails 6`

A few notes:

- $ and jQuery are responding in the console
- jQuery is included **before** other scripts
- jQuery is included **once**.

application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("parsleyjs")
require("bootstrap-datepicker")

import '../stylesheets/application'
import './bootstrap_custom.js'
import './ru.js'
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "joy",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.9.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "parsleyjs": "^2.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.2"
  }
}
```

env.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    Parsley: 'parsleyjs/src/parsley.js',
    datepicker: 'bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

By the way, if I call bootstrap's modal with `data-toggle`, it will open successfully.

Comment: why do you include jquery twice ($ and jQuery) ?

Comment: some jquery plugins refer to jQuery using both $ and jQuery selectors.

Comment: it´s a weird errormessage though `... is not a function in Rails 6` just a wild guess but maybe its because bootstrap comes before jquery in package.json? Whats the exact error-message when you try a native jquery function like `$('div').hide()` ?

Comment: tried that, nothing happens :(

Comment: You should also include jQueryUI this is a solution for older versions, just try with jQueryUI in rails 6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38177237/uncaught-type-error-datepicker-is-not-a-function

Comment: add `require('bootstrap')` in application.js and add `gem bootstrap` to your gemfile.

Comment: @TheWhizofOz were you able to solve the issue?. I am getting similar issue when I try to access selectpicker from bootstrap-select.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code to application.js:

```js
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jquery = jquery;
```

And try changing the jquery in application.js like below.

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
  moment: 'moment/moment',
  datepicker: 'bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js'
}))

module.exports = environment
```